# Built apk extension type shows MobogenieAPK ? i dont know why

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

[image: I built apk in Android studio but its extension shows as Mobogenie apk instead of normal apk.]

I built apk in Android studio but its extension shows as Mobogenie apk instead of normal apk.

Comment: Is the extension of that file ".apk"?

Comment: yes the extension of that file .apk

Comment: Its normal Mobogenie is an application that is open the apk file. Your .apk file is solid.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have installed mobogenie software on your pc. It's valid apk file. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Mobogenie is just your default application to open an apk file. Your apk file is right.